# What is the difference between "had better do something" and "had better be doing something"?

Tags: grammar, difference

What is the difference between *had better do something* and *had better be doing something*? For example:

> It's 8 AM, so **I had better leave** for work if don't want to be late.
>
> It's 8 AM, so **I had better be leaving** for work if don't want to be late.

Does the use of *had better be leaving* implies that it's not really important to me wheter I will be late or not. If I mistaken, then what do native English speakers mean by using the *had better be doing* structure instead of *had better do* one?

Comment: I don't think there is any real difference in meaning. _Be leaving_ implies _prepare to leave_ - it doesn't mean that not being late isn't important, it just suggests that there is still plenty of time.

Comment: So if I said "I had bettee be leaving" it would imply that it is not that urgent as opposed to "had better leave", am I right?

Comment: It suggests to me "It's time for me to get my things together and put my coat on" rather than "I must go right now."

Answer (score 1):

If someone says that you had better do something, they mean you should do that thing. If they say that you had better be doing something, they mean that they expect you to be doing that thing now (or already), and the speaker will be angry (or you will get in trouble, or a bad thing will happen) if you are not.

Comment: Not necessarily "now or soon". Nothing wrong with *You'd better leave a few pounds still owing on your mortgage when it matures **in [x] years time**, because then the building society will continue to look after the title deeds until you actually need them*. But in that example, *You'd better **be leaving** a few pounds...* would be affectation or dialect.